# Cómo resolver el error ¨Unable to detecte application namespace en laravel 5¨

Tags: laravel-5

Este error me sale cuando intento ejecutar un comando con artisan, ejemplo:
php artisan make:Controller myController

Comment: Intentaste realizar el comando usando make:controller con "c" minúscula ? no se si tenga algo que ver pero siempre lo he visto así

Comment: Ejecuta `composer update` avisa si te sale algún error

Comment: Otra es ejecutar `composer dumpautoload` o `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 1):

Este mensaje aparece generalmente por algún error en el archivo composer.json, tal vez te falta cerrar algún `}`, alguna coma adicional o que falte, o puede haber algún error de mayúscula / minúscula en la línea que corresponde al namespace:

```
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
```

También puedes ejecutar `composer diagnose` para ver otros posibles errores